# Replace a folder with another folder using mv (without deleting target folder first)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, mv

I am trying to get a `directory` to replace an existing `folder` but can't get it done with mv - I believe there's a way and I just don't know it (yet). Even after consulting the man page and searching the web.

If `/path/to/` only contains `directory`, the following command will move `/path/to/directory` (vanishes) to `/path/to/folder`

```
mv /path/to/directory /path/to/folder
```

It is basically a rename, which is what I try to achieve.

But if `/path/to/folder` already exists, the same command moves the `/path/to/directory` to `/path/to/folder/directory`.

I do not want to use `cp` command to avoid IO.

Comment: May be: `{ rm -rf /path/to/folder; mv /path/to/directory /path/to/folder; }`

Comment: I know I could move the target away first like this `mv folder moved && mv directory folder && rm -r moved` but I think this is an unnecessary hack and would leave me with a moment where folder does not exist - which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe 
`{ rsync -av /path/to/directory /path/to/folder; }`

Comment: thanks @anubhava for the comment. But deleting the folder is exactly what I intend to avoid.

Comment: There is no shortcut; there are fundamental differences between directories and files, and you can't overwrite one folder with another like this in one step. An important question, though, is why does it matter if `/path/to/folder` doesn't exist momentarily?

Comment: Assuming both `folder` and `directory` are on the same file system, though, you can simply use `ln` instead of `cp` to minimize I/O. `ln /path/to/directory/* /path/to/folder && rm -rf /path/to/directory`.

Comment: Thank you for this informative comment @chepner ! Can you point me to some resource that explains this in more detail? I think this is a fundamental question and deserves a couple of sentences explaining this caveat of replacing folders. The reason is to not run into troubles when running software depends on the `folder`

Comment: In short, `ln <source> <target>` create a new directory entry `<target>` that refers to the same underlying file as `<source>`. Neither name is more of a "real" name than the other; both refer to a file with a link count of 2. In fact, `rm` doesn't actually remove a file; it just removes a *link* to the file. The file system takes care of garbage-collecting files which have no more links to them.

Comment: @chepner If I understand this correctly, the `ln`-way can add and with -f flag replace, but not delete files. Is there a reasonable way to remove files from `folder` that do not exist `directory` in the same go when adding/replacing?

Comment: For that, you would need a tool like `rsync`.

Comment: `rsync -av --delete /path/to/directory/ /path/to/folder` (beware of trailing slashes) is one command that does everything in one go, but I am unaware of the exact sequence of manipulations done by rsync. Code adapted from https://superuser.com/a/623846

Comment: The different `--delete` options of `rsync` allow some extra control over what is deleted and when: `--delete-before`, `--delete-during`, `--delete-delay`, `--delete-after` and `--delete-excluded`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `cp` to actually copy the *data* in each file, use `ln` to make "copies" of the *pointers* to the file.

```
ln /path/to/directory/* /path/to/folder && rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

Note this is *slightly* more atomic than using `cp`; each individual file appears in `/path/to/folder` in a single step (i.e., there is no chance that `/path/to/folder/foo.txt` is ever partially copied), but there is still a small window where some, but not all, files from `/path/to/directory` have been linked to `folder`. Also, the `rm -rf` is not atomic, but assuming no one is interested in `directory`, that's not an issue. (Although, as files from `/path/to/directory` are unlinked, you *can* see changes to the link counts of files under `/path/to/foldoer` changing from 2 to 1. It's unlikely that anyone will care about that.)

---

What you think of as a file is really just a file system entry to an otherwise anonymous file managed by the file system. For example, consider a simple example.

```
$ mkdir d
$ cd d
$ echo hello > file.txt
$ cp file.txt file_copy.txt
$ ln file.txt file_link.txt
$ ls -li
total 24
12890456377 -rw-r--r--  2 chepner  staff  6 Mar  3 12:46 file.txt
12890456378 -rw-r--r--  1 chepner  staff  6 Mar  3 12:47 file_copy.txt
12890456377 -rw-r--r--  2 chepner  staff  6 Mar  3 12:46 file_link.txt
```

The `-i` option adds each entries inode number (the first column) to the output; an inode can be thought of as a unique identifier for a file. In this output, you can see that `file_copy.txt` is an entirely new file, with a different inode than `file.txt`. `file_link.txt` has the exact same inode, meaning that `file.txt` and `file_link.txt` are simply two different names for the same thing. The number just before the owner is the *link count*; `file.txt` and `file_link.txt` both refer to a file with a link count of 2.

When you use `rm`, you are just removing a *link* to a file, not the file itself. A file is not removed until the link count is reduced to 0. To demonstrate, we'll remove `file.txt` and `file_copy.txt`.

```
$ rm file.txt file_copy.txt
$ ls -li
total 8
12890456377 -rw-r--r--  1 chepner  staff  6 Mar  3 12:46 file_link.txt
```

As you can see, the only link to `file_copy` is gone, so inode 12890456378 no longer appears in the output. (Whether or not the data is *really* gone is a matter of file-system implementation.) `file_link.txt`, though, still refers to the same file as before, but now with a link count of 1, because `file.txt` was removed.

Links to a file do not have to appear in the same directory; they can appear in any directory on the same *file system*, which is the only caveat using this trick. `ln` will, IIRC, give you an error if you try to create a link to a file on another file system.